# Magento Extend Module adminhtml Form

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying extend a module that I am using, so that I can add in an extra text input field to the form in the CMS. The module file that builds the CMS form is located in the following location `/app/code/community/Zeon/Manufacturer/Block/Adminhtml/Manufacturer/Edit/Tab/Form.php`. The contents of this file read as such:

```
class Zeon_Manufacturer_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
//code in here
}
```

I have create my custom module and have the following in my config file

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <manufacturer_edit_tab_form>MyModule_ZeonExt_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form</manufacturer_edit_tab_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

My Form.php has the following in it:

```
class MyModule_ZeonExt_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form extends Zeon_Manufacturer_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form {
//edited code in here
}
```

I have extended core classes easily enough, but I can't seem to get the above working, can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <zeon_manufacturer>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_manufacturer_edit_tab_form>MyModule_ZeonExt_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form</adminhtml_manufacturer_edit_tab_form>
            </rewrite>
        </zeon_manufacturer>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**OR**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <manufacturer>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_manufacturer_edit_tab_form>MyModule_ZeonExt_Block_Adminhtml_Manufacturer_Edit_Tab_Form</adminhtml_manufacturer_edit_tab_form>
            </rewrite>
        </manufacturer>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Check this for reference: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The first option was the winner, thank you so much! I was actually using the Inchoo link as reference, but couldn't quite figure out the structure of the config file.